# Black Screen on switching to AMD discrete graphics

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted with Windows 7 on a HP Pavilion 15 n004TX with hybrid graphics, the dedicated AMD being a Radeon HD 8600M series chip. I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) guide to attempt to switch to the integrated AMD graphics. More precisely, here is what I did:

- Add `modprobe radeon.modeset=1` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` field.
- Run `sudo update-grub`.
- Reboot the laptop.
- Run `sudo bash` to use bash as root.
- As root, do `echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`
- Log out to re-log in.

When I log out, the screen immediately goes completely black, and stays black indefinitely.

Some logs and stuff that I think may provide some insight:

- `dmesg | grep vga`:

  ```
  [    0.353271] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
  [   0.353274] vgaarb: device added:  PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
  [    0.353278] vgaarb: loaded
  [    0.353280] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
  [    1.404921] vga_switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.ATPX handle
  [    1.407099] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
  [    1.443796] vga_switcheroo: enabled
  ```
- `dmesg | grep radeon`

  ```
  [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic root=UUID=36fda289-737c-4df7-a5d3-31cdb1af29fe ro quiet splash modprobe radeon.modeset=1 vt.handoff=7
  [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic root=UUID=36fda289-737c-4df7-a5d3-31cdb1af29fe ro quiet splash modprobe radeon.modeset=1 vt.handoff=7
  [    1.404905] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
  [    1.413192] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
  [    1.448380] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
  [    1.448382] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
  [    1.448503] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
  [    1.448504] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
  [    1.456350] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
  [    1.460830] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: WB enabled
  [    1.460832] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c00
  [    1.460834] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c04
  [    1.460835] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c08
  [    1.460837] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c0c
  [    1.460838] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c10
  [    1.460839] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
  [    1.460843] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
  [    1.460883] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
  [    1.460913] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
  [    1.699412] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:0a:00.0 on minor 1
  [   13.343929] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: WB enabled
  [   13.343933] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c00
  [   13.343934] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c04
  [   13.343936] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c08
  [   13.343937] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c0c
  [   13.343939] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c10
  [   13.343941] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
  [   37.170761] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: WB enabled
  [   37.170766] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c00
  [   37.170769] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c04
  [   37.170771] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c08
  [   37.170774] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c0c
  [   37.170776] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800349b0c10
  [   37.170779] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
  ```
- `lspci | grep Display`

  ```
  0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev ff)
  ```
- `lspci | grep VGA`

  ```
  0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev ff)
  ```
- `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

  ```
  OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
  OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
  OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
  OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
  OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
  OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
  OpenGL core profile extensions:
  OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
  OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
  OpenGL context flags: (none)
  OpenGL extensions:
  OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
  OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
  OpenGL ES profile extensions:
  ```

I'll be happy to provide any further information necessary. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: +1 for including the output of all those commands without even being asked! :D

Comment: Nothing yet?? Hmmm....

Comment: You might consider putting a bounty on your question.